# Windows 10 getting HEVC H.265 Codec to use Hardware Acceleration

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player, codec, h.265

Playing HEVC H.265 videos using Windows Media Player and GoPro Quik then the 4k 60 fps video appears all stuttering and becomes a slideshow. The CPU usage is going through the roof and it's not using Hardware Acceleration. I have installed the "HEVC Video Extensions" from Microsoft Store. When I use the app "Movies & TV" for playing the video file then it uses around 1% CPU and Hardware Acceleration seems to be enabled.

How can I get Windows Media Player and GoPro Quik to use Hardware Acceleration?

"HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer" (Free version that works with licence software like GoPro Quik): https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9n4wgh0z6vhq

I have tried following:

1. Uninstall all codecs, also the "HEVC Video Extensions" from Store: Windows Media Player plays only the sound, screen is black. Unable to open video in GoPro Quik
2. Installed K-Lite Codec Pack (w/HEVC codec): Windows Media Player plays the video with both video and audio smoothly. The playback is hardware accelerated as it only used 1% CPU. Unable to open video in GoPro Quik
3. Install "HEVC Video Extensions" from store (Regardless if K-Lite is installed or not): Windows Media Player plays video with both video and audio but it's stuttering. Playback is not hardware accelerated and it uses near 100% CPU. GoPro Quik is now able to open and edit the video but it's stuttering, using 100% CPU on playback and hard to edit the movie

System specifications:

- Windows 10 Pro N, Version 1803, OS Build 17134.165
- Intel i7-8700K @ 3.7Ghz (8th gen, coffee lake, newer then Kaby Lake)
- 16 GB Ram
- Nvidia GeForce 1070 GTX (Driver version 398.82 which is the newest)

One solution would be using software like Handbrake to convert the video file from H.265 to H.264, but I consider that a "hack" as this really should work with my system spec.

Comment: Please provide a link to the HEVC Video Extensions app you downloaded, provider your Windows 10 build, and your full system hardware specifications. Add all this information to the original question by using the EDIT button.

Comment: What makes you think `Windows Media Player` supports hardware acceleration?  I suggest using something other than Windows Media Player to accomplish your task.  Reading the description of the `HEVC Video Extensions`, it does not support `Windows Media Player`, and never was supposed to.  You would have to install a Codec specifically designed for `HEVC Video Extensions`, but even then, you likely would still have performance issues.  There is a good reason Microsoft promotes Movies & TV instead of Windows Media Player on Windows 10

Comment: Maybe the CCCP (codecs package) is what you need? Not sure it already contains HEVC support but I think it has. The codecs installed should be system-wide, in other words available for other apps.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for suggesting this. I installed it and in settings I set it so HEVC should use hardware accelration without much of luick

Comment: did you try other codecs like [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/) or [WinX](https://www.winxdvd.com/hd-video-converter-deluxe/guide-intel-nvidia-hevc-h265-hardware-decoder.htm)?

Comment: @phuclv Yup I have tried K-Lite, not WinX as it looks like it's only for converting H.265 to H.264

Comment: I've been fiddeling around. If I uninstall all codecs and the HEVC Codec app (from store): H.265 files only shows black screen but with sound in Windows Media Player. If I install K-Lite with HEVC Codec then Windows Media Player plays the file with 1% CPU, but GoPro Quik is unable to play and edit the file. If I install HEVC Codec from Windows Store (regardless if K-Lite is installed or not, tried both) then Windows Media Player is again using alot of CPU while playing the video. I'm however able to open the video for editing in Quik but it uses alot of CPU and the playback becomes stuttering.

Comment: Strange. I don't have a GoPro but why doesn't their software support files encoded by their own product? https://www.reddit.com/r/gopro/comments/8781mm/hevch265_ultimate_faq/

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for the link! I also installed DaVinci Resolve and it's the same issue there too!

Comment: you can [create an optimized proxy](https://youtu.be/rT_-JeUVdBM) to work with. The output will be rendered based on the original file

Comment: From what I found, the Quick for Desktop (Windows10) does support the import and playback of HEVC files, but it lacks Hardware acceleration for those HEVC files when you have a Desktop PC with a dedicated graphics card where you cannot switch between integrated and dedicated graphics as you can on a laptop, as often suggested as a solution. Consequently, I think that for hardware acceleration you need to wait for an update to GoPro Quik.

Comment: @harrymc Feel free to add a answer where this is the conclusion and I'll change the correct answer to yours :)

Comment: Done as requested. Quite cheeky, putting up my comment as an answer, but at least honestly done with giving credit.

Comment: @harrymc Great, I sat it as answer now. Cheeky, but people looking at this question would like to see an answer in the answers and not in the comments ;) Aslong as I qouted with your name and date then it should be alright, but also why I wanted you to answer it so you got the proper credits and points for it :)

Comment: Understood and no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I found, the Quick for Desktop (Windows10) does support the import
and playback of HEVC files, but it lacks Hardware acceleration for those HEVC files
when you have a Desktop PC with a dedicated graphics card where you cannot switch
between integrated and dedicated graphics as you can on a laptop,
as often suggested as a solution.

Consequently, I think that for hardware acceleration you need to wait for an update to GoPro Quik. This capability is simply missing in the software and there is no
setting to be turned on.

Comment: I wanted to add: GoPro Quik uses the codec from the store app "HEVC Video Extensions" and it's unknown if the problem is the codec from the store, or if it's the implementation of this codec in GoPro Quik.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get it for free.

Copy/paste this link into the browser:

```
ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq
```

Or, open command prompt, and type/paste:

```
start ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq
```

Click "Install".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft removed free support from Windows 10. To re-enable the HEVC codec they are charging a ransom in their Windows Store: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NMZLZ57R3T7
[image: .99Dollars]
At the time of writing it costs 99 cents.
[image]

A comment below says that this is free. It might have been but it is no longer free.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you did read the question, but they already provides a free version, paid version is not needed for GoPro Quik and doesn't solve the problem as I've tried that: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9n4wgh0z6vhq

Comment: Dang, they seem to have removed the free version from being available.